# Is my usage of predicates here bad practice or extra?

Tags: java, predicate, naming

I'm making a card game, and I may be over-engineering a bit. Before I had methods `pileHasMostSpades()` and `pileHasMostSevens()`. These methods had the same code barring an if condition and an integer value. I was able to combine these methods into one (`pileHasAtLeast()`) by adding a predicate and an integer parameter.

`pileHasAtLeast(count, predicate)` - checks if there are at least [count] cards that match the predicate.

Also, what would be alternative or perhaps better names for this new style of method (`pileHasAtLeast()`)? Thank you.

```
public int computeScore()
{
    int score = scopas;
    
    final Predicate<Card> spades = c -> c.getSuit() == Card.Suit.SPADES;
    final Predicate<Card> sevens = c -> c.getValue() == Card.Value.SEVEN;
    
    score += pile.size() > 20 ? 1 : 0;
    score += pileHasAtLeast(6, spades) ? 1 : 0;
    score += pileHasAtLeast(3, sevens) ? 1 : 0;
    score += hasSevenOfSpades() ? 1 : 0;
    
    return score;
}

private boolean pileHasAtLeast(int count, Predicate<Card> predicate)
{
    int result = 0;
    
    for(Card card : pile)
    {
        if(predicate.test(card))
        {
            result++;
        }
    }
    
    return result > count;
}
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need a dedicated method for that, you can write `pile.stream().filter(c -> c.getSuit() == Card.Suit.SPADES).count() > 6`

Comment: also your predicate would be (in my opinion) better named as `isSpade` than `spades`

Comment: and strictly regarding the name of the method: it's not "at least", it's "more than" (unless that's a bug and it should be `>=` instead of `>`)

Comment: The original methods probably make the code more readable (though that's just my opinion). But you could of course have those methods delegate to the `Predicate`-accepting method to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, that's a bug that I fixed right after posting, thanks!

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the alternative! I'll definitely use that instead!

Comment: @Slaw I'm going to use njzk2's alternative but I'll keep delegation in mind for better readability in other programs. Great suggestion

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

That is the case here too. Predicates are nice, but here, especially with `score += ... ? 1 : 0;` lines, the full low level logic is pressed into a specific form.

It would be better to write out the code, and then again add abstractions.

I still would not write off predicates. But not on a card but on a pile.

Should you want your score explained (for beginners of the game), single predicates together with its score and a explanatory text `"* 1 Point: " + "more than 6 spades"`

Borrowing @nzjk2's Stream replacement:

```
record ScoreRule(int score, Predicate<Pile>, String explanation);

ScoreRule[] scoreRules = {
    new ScoreRule(1,
        pile -> pile.size() > 20,
        "more than 20 cards"),
    new ScoreRule(1,
        pile -> pile.stream().filter(c -> c.getSuit() == Card.Suit.SPADES).count() > 6,
        "more than 6 spades"),
    new ScoreRule(...),
    ...
};
... score counting and reporting ...
```

The reason that this works better, is that the pile as a whole is the case to be handled, and a Stream has much evalution logic, and expressive query power such as count, contains, all matches, none matches.

Comment: Interesting approach! Though how would I go about computing the score? Iterate through the ScoreRule[] and test against the predicate for every rule?

Comment: @Picarrow yes, and again a Stream of the array is possible, filtering on true predicates and summing the scores. But iteration is fine. I like this declarative approach: a high level model of the logic.

Comment: Now that is crazy powerful, I gotta start thinking like that lol! Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

I've done some refactoring for your code

```
public int computeScore()
{
   //here we count all of the conditions that are true (won't work if you need to add different score for each condition)
   return scopas + Stream.of(pile.size() > 20,
                             pileHasAtLeast(6, c -> c.getSuit() == Card.Suit.SPADES),
                             pileHasAtLeast(3, c -> c.getValue() == Card.Value.SEVEN),
                             pileHasAtLeast(1, c -> c.getValue() == Card.Value.SEVEN) 
                                            && c.getSuit() == Card.Suit.SPADES)
                       .filter(condition -> condition)
                       .count();
}


private boolean pileHasAtLeast(int count, Predicate<Card> predicate)
{
    return count <= pile.stream()
         .filter(predicate)
         .count();
}
```

Several tips:

- Don't mix imperative loops like "for" with functional programming. Use streams whenever you have no side effects.
- Don't store predicates you use only once in a variable, you lose the power of functional programming.

Comment: Answering your question: using predicates is a good practice. In your case, it's better to use them inline.

Comment: Nice refactor, though I'm not sure about the second tip and the styling in your code. I used the variables to make my code more readable. I'm looking at your code and it's tough to read due to all the tabs and unexplained conditions. I wanted to name the predicates so that they could be more quickly understood by readers. Is poor readability a consequence of functional programming or is there a better solution?

Comment: @Picarrow I don't find it less readable. Maybe, you're just not used to functional, I don't know. Formatting though can be changed to whatever is more suitable to you.

Comment: That's definitely true! I'm not used to functional yet. But I'm not sure if there is a better way to format it lol. I guess I'll have to get used to it.